# Jquery Timepicker - schedule time to 6hrs from current time

Tags: javascript, timepicker

I have used a jquery timepicker, as below

[image: jQuery timepicker]
Below is my code :

```
$('#timePicker').timepicker({
    'step': 15,
    'forceRoundTime': true,
    'timeFormat': 'H:i'
});
$('#timePicker').timepicker('setTime', new Date(new Date().getTime()+6*3600*1000));
```

My problem is that I am getting 6hrs ahead of my current time, but I also need to disable the previous time.

For example:

If current date time is 04th April, 2016 11.50 AM - then the time picker should show 04th April, 2016 17.50 PM, and if date is not today then time picker should allow all time to select.

Please let me know what changes should I make in my code?

Comment: do you have a separate datepicker also

Comment: yes, i need date picker & time picker separate

Comment: @TanmayMhatre look at my Answer this may be help you.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rngwefrh/3/?

Comment: Thanks @Arun P Johny, your fiddle is perfect what i want..

Comment: can we have Indian Standard Time in time picker instead of System Time, as once can edit the system time and time picker time can get change..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are after is

```js
var min = new Date(),
  strMin = $.datepicker.formatDate("mm/dd/yy", min);
min.setHours(min.getHours() + 6);
$('#datePicker').datepicker({
  minDate: min,
  onSelect: function(v) {
    console.log(v == strMin ? formatTime(min) : '12:00am')
    $('#timePicker').timepicker('option', 'minTime', v == strMin ? formatTime(min) : '12:00am');
  }
}).datepicker('setDate', min);

$('#timePicker').timepicker({
  'step': 15,
  'forceRoundTime': true,
  'timeFormat': 'H:i',
  'minTime': formatTime(min)
});
$('#timePicker').timepicker('setTime', min);


function formatTime(dt) {
  return dt.getHours() + ':' + ('0' + dt.getMinutes()).slice(-2) + (dt.getHours() >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am')
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-timepicker/1.8.11/jquery.timepicker.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-timepicker/1.8.11/jquery.timepicker.js"></script>
<input id="datePicker" />
<input id="timePicker" />
```

Comment: thanks for providing this solution, but can we have IST instead of system Time in timepicker?

As system time can be changed anytime and booking can be done

Comment: @DhawalMhatre in that case the current time must be passed from the server to client

Comment: but server time can be of USA or UK according to server location

Comment: in your code the time is not rounding off to 15 mins interval on current date.. srry to keep asking question

Comment: @DhawalMhatre timezone conversion can be done in the server side

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108149/discussion-between-dhawal-mhatre-and-arun-p-johny).

Answer (score 0):

best way to do that is to always call the `onHourShow` function and `validate the selected date` in that function. I think this is better because the `disabled hours are still visible` to the user instead of `blank cells`.

```
$('#date').datepicker({
    minDate: 0
});
$('#time').timepicker({
    onHourShow: function( hour ) { 
        var now = new Date();
        // compare selected date with today
        if ( $('#date').val() == $.datepicker.formatDate ( 'mm/dd/yy', now ) ) {
            if ( hour <= now.getHours() ) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
});​
```

here is a working example :
http://jsfiddle.net/fgelinas/kUFgT/4/

Comment: i think he is reffering to [jquery.timepicker](http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/) and not jquery.ui datetime picker

Answer (score 0):

according to the [documentation](http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/) you can disable the previous time by using DisableTimeRanges

```
function formatAMPM(date) {
  var hours = date.getHours();
  var minutes = date.getMinutes();
  var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
  hours = hours % 12;
  hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
  minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0'+minutes : minutes;
  var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + '' + ampm;
  return strTime;
}

time_plus_6 = new Date(new Date().getTime()+6*3600*1000);
$('#timePicker').timepicker({
        'step': 15,
    'forceRoundTime': true,
    'timeFormat': 'H:i',
    'disableTimeRanges': [
        [0, formatAMPM(time_plus_6)]
    ]
});

$('#timePicker').timepicker('setTime', time_plus_6);
```

working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n23h6ac1/)