# jQuery UI datetimepicker: Disable current time and past times. On Future dates enable all times

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker, datetimepicker

I'm having some trouble disabling the current time ex. If date time is 12th December 2018 - 10:00am and **All** past times **Before** 10:00am needs to be disabled.

However I would like to find a way to then **re-enable** those times when choosing a **future** date and re-enabling those times.

Here is the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rngwefrh/4/

```
var min = new Date(),
  strMin = $.datepicker.formatDate("mm/dd/yy", min);
min.setHours(min.getHours() + 6);
min.setMinutes(min.getMinutes() + (15 - min.getMinutes() % 15))
$('#datePicker').datepicker({
  minDate: min,
  onSelect: function(v) {
    $('#timePicker').timepicker('option', 'minTime', v == strMin ? formatTime(min) : '12:00am');
  }
}).datepicker('setDate', min);

$('#timePicker').timepicker({
  'step': 15,
  'forceRoundTime': true,
  'timeFormat': 'H:i',
  'minTime': formatTime(min)
});
$('#timePicker').timepicker('setTime', min);


function formatTime(dt) {
  return dt.getHours() + ':' + ('0' + dt.getMinutes()).slice(-2) + (dt.getHours() >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am')
}

<input id="datePicker" />
<input id="timePicker" />
```

*The fiddle on top was taken by this question: [Jquery Timepicker - schedule time to 6hrs from current time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36395752/jquery-timepicker-schedule-time-to-6hrs-from-current-time)*

---

I then found another fiddle that was taken by the same stackoverflow question on top which is something similar in what I was looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/n23h6ac1/

```
function formatAMPM(date) {
  var hours = date.getHours();
  var minutes = date.getMinutes();
  var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
  hours = hours % 12;
  hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
  minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0'+minutes : minutes;
  var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + '' + ampm;
  return strTime;
}

time_plus_6 = new Date(new Date().getTime()+1*3600*1000);
$('#timePicker').timepicker({
        'step': 15,
    'forceRoundTime': true,
    'timeFormat': 'H:i',
    'disableTimeRanges': [
        [0, formatAMPM(time_plus_6)]
    ]
});

$('#timePicker').timepicker('setTime', time_plus_6);

<input id="timePicker">
```

This however does disable current times **AND** past times, but it does it re-enable **ALL** times when choosing another future date.

I apologise for the long question. Any help would be so great!